# Extending SuperTest

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

I like to use [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to work with my auth system like this:

```
    const request = require('./valid_access_token')(require('supertest'));

    request(app)
    .get('/v1/bots')
    .valid_token()
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    ...
```

valid_token() would insert a valid access-token

```
    module.exports = function (Request) {

      const Token = require('../../../app/v1/models/loader')('token');
      const UserFactory = require('../fixtures/user');

      Request.prototype.valid_token = function()
      {

        return UserFactory.createAsync('user')
        .then(function(user){
            return new Token({username: user.username}).createWeeklyAsync()
            .then(function(userToken){
                this.set("access-token",userToken[0].token);
                return this;
            })       
        })     
       }        
       return Request;
    }
```

However, when I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: request(...).get(...).valid_token is not a function
```

I tried various different approaches, no luck.

Answer (score 4):

All the credit goes to https://github.com/acabreragnz

```
const request = require('supertest');
const Test = request.Test;

Test.prototype.authenticate = function(user) {
  const {token, xsrfToken} = user.tokens;

  return this
   .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
   .set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken);
}
```

Then in your tests

```
return request(app)
  .post('/user/settings')
  .authenticate(user)
  .send(...)
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/381#issuecomment-282198972