# Extending supertest in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, bdd, supertest

I'm trying to create a extension on supertest.

Using what I found in question [Extending SuperTest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47682059/1233788). I have this working example on `javascript`:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const Test = request.Test;

Test.prototype.authenticate = function(user) {
  const {token, xsrfToken} = user.tokens;

  return this
   .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
   .set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken);
}
```

And inside a test block I can use:

```
request(app)
  .post('/user/settings')
  .authenticate(user)
  .send(...)
```

This works fine. The problem now is to use the extension in a `*.test.ts` file.

As suggested in [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/1233788), I try to create a file to use the typescript feature  [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

```
// file location: ./src/types/supertest

declare namespace supertest {
  export interface Test {
    authenticate(user: any): this; // I didn't put a type on user to simplify here.
  }
}
```

and also changed my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],

    ...

  }
}
```

But when I run `npx tsc`

```
$ npx tsc
src/api/user.test.ts:51:8 - error TS2551: Property 'authenticate' does not exist on type 'Test'.

51       .authenticate(user);
          ~~~~~~~
```

**Question**
Is there a way to fix this on typescript environment?

**[EDIT]**
**Extra Information (not necessarily useful):**
In the same project I have extensions on `express`, `chai` and `pdf-merge-js`. All of them works fine using the approach described above.

There is something peculiar about `supertest` maybe about `@types/supertest` that is preventing it to work.

This is a little bit of the code in my project that already work's for express:

```
// file location: ./src/types/express
import { ModelBase } from '../../models/base';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Response {
      model: (model: ModelBase) => this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At this answer [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/40762463#40762463) it says you have to add the **whole file path** to `tsconfig.json` **`files`** array, not `typeRoots`. Try to add the file to `files` inside `tsconfig`.

Comment: In my project I have extensions for express and chai all work perfectly, using this setup, only supertest didn't work. But I tested your theory anyway, didn't work, thanks for the help.

Comment: I updated the question with a little more information.

Comment: It's not my theory, it's what the answer you're referencing suggests and you're missing.

Comment: Can you try to add this file in your user.test.ts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about add. If is to put the interface inside the test file, the problem will be that if I declare somenthing inside of the file I cannot import something else with the same name.

Comment: I mean import './src/types/supertest'; not the interface just this and it should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but this worked for me:

```
declare module "supertest" {
  interface Test extends superagent.SuperAgentRequest {
    authenticate(user: any): this;
  }
}
```

Structure:

```
index.ts
tsconfig.json
types
  - supertest
    - index.d.ts
```

My `index.ts`:

```
import request from "supertest";
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.get("/user", function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: "john" });
});

request(app)
  .post("/user/settings")
  .authenticate({ tokens: { token: "", xsrfToken: "" } })
  .send();
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "files": ["./types/supertest/index.d.ts", "index.ts"]
}
```

My `types/supertest/index.d.ts`:

```
import superagent from "superagent";

declare module "supertest" {
  interface Test extends superagent.SuperAgentRequest {
    authenticate(user: any): this;
  }
}
```

I think that `declare module "supertest"` is the key part. Everything else you got right.

Comment: This worked even without changes on `tsconfig.json`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

This one worked for me well.

First I've imported types

```
npm i -D @types/supertest
```

And then I've used

```
import { agent as request } from "supertest";
```

Answer (score -3):

I'd trough with this problem and i solve it just import on test file

```js
import { agent as request } from "supertest";
```

Comment: that makes no sense lmao